# Pass data to a directive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

In the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) it states that you can pass various arguments to a directive.

So I want to pass in a value:

```
v-my-directive="test"
```

But I get the error:

```
Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render
```

How can I pass in a string to a directive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value is a regular JavaScript expression. This way, if you want to pass a string, say `'test'`, use:

```
v-my-directive="'test'"
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.directive('my-directive', function (el, binding) {
  console.log('directive expression:', binding.value)  // => "test"
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <div v-my-directive="'test'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: console.log(el.value); is blank with this.

Comment: That should be in `console.log(binding.value)`, actually.

Comment: Thanks - missed that one!

Comment: Added a demo, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote the string, otherwise it will look for the `test` variable in your component context (its `props` or `data`):

```
v-my-directive="'test'"
```

Inside your custom directive, you can access the passed value as in the `binding.value`:

```
Vue.directive('demo', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    var s = JSON.stringify
    el.innerHTML =
      'name: '       + s(binding.name) + '<br>' +
      'value: '      + s(binding.value) + '<br>' +
      'expression: ' + s(binding.expression) + '<br>' +
      'argument: '   + s(binding.arg) + '<br>' +
      'modifiers: '  + s(binding.modifiers) + '<br>' +
      'vnode keys: ' + Object.keys(vnode).join(', ')
  }
})
```

See the [Custom Directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) chapter of the guide.

Comment: console.log(el.value); is blank with this.

Comment: inside the directive you have to use `binding.value` to access the value