# Custom vue directive (like v-model) for using getter/setter without computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a component system that will let other developers write vue applications with the components to quickly get up and running with simple forms.

My components are very general, and expect plain values to be bound to their `value` property, and will emit plain values with their `input` events.

The data we want the components to control is complex. I've read that you cannot use classes as vue data, because vue expects plain javascript objects for data. So each piece of data is an object like

```
{
  _value: ...
  setVal(): ...
  getVal(): ...
}
```

And we are binding like

```
<my-component
  :value="dataObject.getVal()"
  @input="dataObject.setVal($event)"
/>
```

I thought it might be possible to write a vue directive to shorthand those properties, like how v-model is a shorthand for :value and @input normally, so that I could write

```
<my-component v-my-directive="dataObject" />
```

and it automatically binds the right thing to :value and the right thing to @input, but it doesn't seem to be that simple. I've found tutorials that mention twoway for Vue v1 directives, but that was removed in Vue v2, which recommended using a wrapper component as a replacement. But we have a large library of components, writing and maintaining a wrapper for each one seems out of line for just creating a shorthand like what already exists. Is there any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass data to a directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005159/pass-data-to-a-directive)

Comment: That does not answer the question at all, Steven's answer is maybe a bit closer, it's at least an authoritative "no thats not possible". In my example I clearly show how to pass data to the directive (the dataObject reference). It's the binding of data emitted from the child component the directive was added to, back to the parent component that attached that directive (as if @input="dataObject.setVal($event)" was specified) that seems impossible.

Comment: I can't add an answer because this one got closed incorrectly, but we settled on creating a proxy for the dataObject, and passing a dummy key as the binding. E.g. "v-model="createProxy(dataObject)._", and then the proxy disregards the "_" key and uses the appropriate getter and setter as applicable. I'll open up a new question and answer it myself in more detail if anyone else upvotes this comment to indicate they are looking for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hey Austin, please share your solution if you've been figured out. I'm hardly looking for a solution to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Hey @Babaktrad, this question is actually really outdated now. Vue 3 supports classes as reactive data. I can't remember what the exact code we cooked up was, but have you tried just using a class with a normal getter setter property, and hooking up the component to that property?

Comment: @Austin, No I didn't. Actually I don't know how to implement a class-based data property in Vue2.x. The main problem that I'm trying to solve is that finding a way to replace a data property with a computed property constructed with getter and setter on the fly! This is because I need to get a masked value and set a real value for an input tag.

Answer (score 0):

vue2 only allows v-model directive to be bound to :value/@input.  So you need to use both v-bind and @on directives for 2 way binding.

vue3 combines these using a convention that allows for multiple v-model bindings

You create a prop called 'foo' and emit and event called 'update:foo' with the value you want to assign to it.

The parent component uses `v-model:foo` to bind to it.